# ESP32 WIFI webclient returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: request, webclient, esp32

have been trying to make this web request work for a while but no success.

This same request on a browser works good (copied from the serial terminal as the ESP32 generates it):
caxiasmed.com/esp32/insert.php?jd=1234567&area=Area01&type=h&value=125
Assistance welcome.
Code below.
Thanks
Paulo

```
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* ssid     = "SkyNet";
const char* password = "ba21ca";
const char* host = "caxiasmed.com";

int    jd    = 1234567;
char  *area  = "Area01";
char   type  = 'h';
int    value = 125;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);

    // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);

    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }

    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
    Serial.println("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop(){
    String  url;

    Serial.print("connecting to ");
    Serial.println(host);

    // Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections
    WiFiClient client;
    const int httpPort = 80;
    if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
        Serial.println("connection failed");
        return;
    } 
    url  = "/esp32/insert.php?";
    url += "jd=";            
    url += jd;
    url += "&area=";            
    url += area;
    url += "&type=";
    url += 'h';
    url += "&value=";
    url += value;

    Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
    Serial.println(url);


    // This will send the request to the server
    client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                 "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");

/*
    Serial.println("#################################URL:");
    Serial.print("GET ");
    Serial.print(url);
    Serial.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    Serial.print("Host: ");
    Serial.println(host);
    Serial.println("Connection: close");
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("#####################################");
*/                 
    unsigned long timeout = millis();
    while (client.available() == 0) {
        if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
            Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
            client.stop();
            return;
        }
    }

    // Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to Serial
    while(client.available()) {
        String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
        Serial.print(line);
    }

    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("closing connection");

    delay(15000);
}
```

When I run the sketch with the serial console on I get the confirmation of the WiFi connection.
In the serial console I also get confirmation that the http connection with the "host" took place successfully then, when the following section of the script is executed:

```
// This will send the request to the server
    client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                 "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
```

Something goes wrong and the web server returns a html formatted error message that is printed on the serial console when the following line is executed:

```
// Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to Serial
while(client.available()) {
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.print(line);
}
```

This response includes the message 400 BAD REQUEST as if the GET above was incorrectly formatted.

For reference I am including the insert.php that is actually called by the ESP32 code posted previously:

```
<?php

   include('connection.php');

   $jd    = $_GET['jd'];
   $area  = $_GET['area'];
   $type  = $_GET['type'];
   $value = $_GET['value'];

   $sql = "INSERT INTO activity (jd,area,type,value) VALUES (:jd,:area,:type,:value)";

   $stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);

   $stmt->bindParam(':jd',$jd);
   $stmt->bindParam(':area',$area);
   $stmt->bindParam(':type',$type);
   $stmt->bindParam(':value',$value);

   if($stmt->execute()) {

      echo "Sucessful SQL Insertion";

   } else {
      echo "SQL Insert Failed.";
}
?>
```

As I said, if I copy the GET request line from the serial terminal screen that is monitoring the running application and paste it on a web browser it will successfully insert the data in the SQL database as per php code above.

Assistance welcome.
Thanks
Paulo Borges

Comment: Did you get any solution!? I am facing the same problem now

Comment: I abandoned this method all together. Now I use a general purpose php script https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/puravidaapps/mysql.php. On the Arduino side check the following link: https://community.appybuilder.com/t/arduino-project-that-calls-a-mysql-database/24188.

Comment: Arduino URLENCODE: String urlencode(const String &s) {
  static const char lookup[]= "0123456789abcdef";
  String result;
  size_t len = s.length();
  for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    const char c = s[i];
    if(('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') || ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') || ('0' <= c && c <= '9') || (c=='-' || c=='_' || c=='.' || c=='~')) {  // || c=='\''
      result += c;
    } else {
      result += "%" + String(lookup[(c & 0xf0) >>4]) + String(lookup[c & 0x0f]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and in my case was a missing parameter in the request header. If you have a successful request in your browser, you can do this:

1. Download a terminal capable of creating a TCP server. I suggest the [Hercules terminal](https://www.hw-group.com/software/hercules-setup-utility);
2. Create a TCP server on a known port, like 8000;
3. Make the request on your browser, but using the host "localhost:8000" and see what comes to the terminal. You will be able to see the raw data, which is the same data that you have to send trough ESP32.

Probably you are missing some parameters on the header that the server that you are working with need to be sent. Try to copy the full request and, after that works, remove the unnecessary parameters.

Here is an example of a RAW request:

[image: Request raw on terminal]

Let us know if you solve the problem. Good luck!

Comment: Please check added comments above